# IOS Apply a slow motion effect to a video while shooting

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Is it possible to apply slow motion effect while recording video?

This means that the recording has not finished yet, the file has not been saved, but the user sees the recording process in slow motion.

Comment: Life is not in slow motion, so what would "slow motion video in real time" even mean?

Comment: The idea is to do video processing in real time.
A person makes a filming of some event, and through the screen he sees it in slow motion.

Comment: Ok but that's not "real time".

Comment: I have corrected the description. Hope it's clearer this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is important to understand what slow-motion actually means. To "slow down motion" in a movie, you need to film more images per second than usually and play this movie afterwards in normal speed, that's making the slow motion effect.

Example: Videos are often shot in 30 frames per second (fps), so for one second of movie you're creating 30 single images. If you want a motion to be half as fast, you need to shoot 60 fps (60 images per second). If you play those 60 images at half-speed (the normal 30fps), it will result in a movie of 2 second lengths showing the slow-motion effect.

As you can see, you cannot record and show a slow-motion effect at the same time. You'll need to save it first and then play it slower than recorded.

Comment: Maybe is it possible to cut video in small pieces and save them into buffer and process them?

Comment: Your whole idea is physically impossible as you cannot show a motion which has not finished yet

Comment: I understood you. Thanks for help. You saved me a lot of time )